# Submit form after reCaptcha is solved

Tags: plugins, captcha

I have installed WP plugin for reCaptcha & add it on registration page, everything is OK but it submit the form before reCaptcha is solved. 
I don't want to mess with WP code and do something stupid,I know i need to add statement like, if reCaptcha is solved then submit, but where to add that statement.
Thanks for the help.

Comment: which plugin you have used

Comment: Google Captcha (reCAPTCHA) by BestWebSoft